# Как изменить порядок столбца id для таблицы, не меняя другие столбцы

Tags: mysql, sql

Как изменить порядок столбца id для таблицы, не меняя другие столбцы?

```
1 name_1 tel_1
2 name_2 tel_2
3 name_3 tel_3
```

а нужно

```
3 name_1 tel_1
2 name_2 tel_2
1 name_3 tel_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При всём [censored] задачи:

```
UPDATE table t1
JOIN ( SELECT 1 + MAX(id) maxid
       FROM table t2 ) t3
SET t1.id = t3.maxid - t1.id;
```

Если `id` - первичный или уникальный индекс, то удалить его перед обновлением и пересоздать после.